# No validation on lost focus calendarextender

Tags: asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have calendarextender for a textbox. I need do the requiredfiled validation after lost focus. But the code below doesn't show red * after lost focus.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDateS" runat="server" Width="80px"/>
<cc1:calendarextender ID="ceDateS" runat="server" CssClass="cal" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="txtDateS" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDates" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" Text="*" ControlToValidate="txtDateS"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="rfvDates_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="rfvDates"></cc1:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RequiredFieldValidator doesn't fire when the control loses focus (unless you've previously entered text and then removed it), what you can try is to add the following to the page load event:

```
txtDateS.Attributes.Add("onblur", "ValidatorOnChange(event);")
```